# view's alpha in IOS5 is different?

Tags: ios5, alpha

I have a `UITextView`.
The view's alpha is 0.2.
The text color is white.

It looks normal in simulator4.3 and device(IOS4.2.1)

But it looks too transparent in device(IOS 5). 
It feels like the alpha is 0.1 or even less.

Why? Is the alpha's algorithm in IOS5 updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve this question. The reseaon is that i set the textcolor's alpha in accident,but in IOS4 the textcolor's alpha is not work. so i also set the view's alpha to do it. so in IOS4(in IOS4 the textcolor's alpha is not work),the text looks normal. But in IOS5(IOS5 support the textcolor's alpha) the text's alpha is textcolor'alpha*view's alpha.....

Answer (score 0):

No.

What kind of device is the 4.2.1 v. the iOS 5? The screens on the iPhone 4 and 4s are much crisper looking and could cause this appearance.

Comment: I just solve this question. The reseaon is that i set the textcolor's alpha in accident,but in IOS4 the textcolor's alpha is not work. so i also set the view's alpha to do it.
so in IOS4(in IOS4 the textcolor's alpha is not work),the text looks normal.
But in IOS5(IOS5 support the textcolor's alpha) the text's alpha is textcolor'alpha*view's alpha.....